# Why do sticky prices make output partly determined by demand?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, monetary-policy, central-banking, new-keynesian-economics

First time going through the basic new-keynesian model and i understand the math behind it okay. I also get that output being partly demand determined is the transmission mechanism for monetary policy in the model but im struggling to see through the maths and get intuition to why nominal rigidities cause output to be demand determined.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you understand math I will focus only on intuition.

Price rigidities imply that level of prices can have real effect on output, at least in short run. Also generally higher prices will have positive effect on output and lower prices negative effect on output in short run. The exact reason for this depends on nature of nominal rigidities. For example, if there are rigidities in labor market (nominal fixed contracts, or high minimum wages) then increase in price level lowers real cost of labor and allows firms to hire more people and vice versa.

The price level depends on aggregate demand, even if fundamental reason for increase in price level might lie deeper (e.g. money market which is part of IS-LM from which you derive AD), it is the intersection of aggregate demand and supply that determines the price level in New Keynesian models. So you can view it as output being determined by aggregate demand in a sense that if there is more aggregate demand more will be produced in short run.